# Trying to replace a normal var with % in a print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, printing

Basically I'm learning some python basics and without issues executed the below:

`print(var1 + ' ' + (input('Enter a number to print')))`

Now I'm trying to print the output of the variable along with the string stating "You have entered" using the % method.

Have tried this apart from other code:
`print(%s + ' ' + (input('Enter a number to print')) %(var))` but gives a syntax error on the %s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
print('%s %s'%(var1, input('Enter a number to print')))
```

The `%s` goes inside the quotes, and indicates the position of the elements you want to insert in the string.

Comment: This is more basic for me to comprehend. Small question, I see that print('%s'%(var1, input('Enter a number to print'))) fails to compile with error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting". What is the effect of using %s %s instead of only one %s. Thanks in advance!

Comment: With `%s %s` you're trying to insert two elements in your string. `var1` goes into the position of the first `%s`, and the result of your `input` goes in the position of your second `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't. This way of formatting strings is from python 2.x and there are far batter ways to deal with string formatting in python 3.x:

- [string.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)
- [pep 498 [3.6+]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) or [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and also [format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

---

### Your code has 2 problems:

```
print(var1 + ' ' + (input('Enter a number to print')))
```

is, if `var1` is a string it works - if not it crashes:

```
var1 = 8
print(var1 + ' ' + (input('Enter a number to print')))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(var1 + ' ' + (input('Enter a number to print')))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

You could do

```
var1 = 8
print(var1 , ' ' + (input('Enter a number to print')))
```

but then you lost the ability to format `var1`. Also: the `input` is evaluated *before* the `print`, so its text is on one line, followed by the `print`-statements output - why put them into the same line then?

### Better:

```
var1 = 8

# this will anyhow be printed in its own line before anyway
inp = input('Enter a number to print')

# named formatting (you provide the data to format as tuples that you reference
# in the {reference:formattingparams}
print("{myvar:>08n} *{myInp:^12s}*".format(myvar=var1,myInp=inp))

# positional formatting - {} are filled in same order as given to .format()
print("{:>08n} *{:^12s}*".format(var1,inp))

# f-string 
print(f"{var1:>08n} *{inp:^12s}*")

# showcase right align w/o leading 0 that make it obsolete
print(f"{var1:>8n} *{inp:^12s}*")
```

Output:

```
00000008 *   'cool'   *
00000008 *   'cool'   *
00000008 *   'cool'   *
       8 *   'cool'   *
```

The mini-format parameters mean:

```
:>08n    right align, fill with 0 to 8 digits (which makes the > kinda obsolete)
         and n its a number to format

:^12s    center in 12 characters, its a string
```

---

Have a look at [print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) as well. It has several options to control the output - f.e. what to use as seperator if multiple things are given:

```
print(1,2,3,4,sep="--=--") 
print(  *[1,2,3,4], sep="\n")  # *[...] provides the list elemes as single params to print
```

Output:

```
1--=--2--=--3--=--4

1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Works nicely, a bit advanced but will get there soon :D Many thanks for your time!